# Entity Framework LINQ - Using additional Where clause with Join significantly slows down query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The addition of the last line slows requests from a second to 5 seconds plus, and making requests seconds apart causes hangs of over 10 seconds:

```
from b in db.Books
join u in
    (from x in db.UsersBooks where x.UserID == userID select x) on b.ID equals u.BookID into gj
from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    ID = b.ID,
    BookName = b.Name,
    UsersRating = subpet.Rating,
    UsersComment = subpet.Comment,
    Awards = db.Awards.Where(a => (a.bookID == b.ID))
};
```

I'm considering returning the Awards using a separate API call for each book, though this seems a bit ridiculous, is such a hang expected with this kind of query?

Comment: Analyze the generated query (queries). We can't do that for you. Side note: use navigation properties, not joins and manual subqueries).

Comment: This is likely due to missing indexes. Does `Award.BookId` have a FK reference to `Book.Id`? Also, if separate requests are causing each other to hang, something else must be blocking it? Are you hitting a SQLite DB? Are you using async? Are you using transactions?

Comment: No FK reference set up, so this should improve it? MS SQL Sever Express. Not using transactions or async...

Comment: Is there a reason  we query dB.Awards so late? Can we not  left join as well dB.books and dB.Awards on book.Id equals award.bookId?

Comment: I think that returns multiple rows with the same book...? I'm aiming for all books to be returned in db.Books and if a user has saved any data against that book then to return that , and also return any awards tied the book. At the end of this I parse it to JSON.

Comment: It is Eager Loading query. Standard cure is to add `AsSplitQuery()`, but note, it will work only from EF Core 6 +